# How do I query a Meteor.publication collection by a component prop correctly?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Given the following React component, I am passing this component this.ticket.props AND I am subscribing to a collection called userReservations.  The ticket properties are rendering correctly i.e. each ticket is rendering only it's specific properties.

However inside the .renderReservationInfo() method.  After I make the Meteor.subscription call with the ticket._id value as a selector in the createContainer class, which corresponds to the "ticketId" value in the UserReservation collection, the Meteor publication responds with the correct collection info but renders it to every ticket.

If I'm querying by ticket._id, why is the collection applied to both tickets?  How can I render just the reservation info to the corresponding ticket._id?

Are there react lifecycle components that can help me manage this?

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component {

renderReservationInfo() {
    let {
        ticket,
        UserReservation
    } = this.props;
    return UserReservation.map((reservation) => {
        return ( 
          <div key = {reservation._id} >
            < h4 > {reservation.property1} < /h4> 
            < h4 > {reservation.property2} < /h4> 
            < h4 > {reservation.property3} < /h4> 
            <Component2 prop = {reservation} /> 
          </div >
        )
    });
  }


render() {
    return ( 
      <div >
        < div className = "make-it-pretty" >
            < h4 > Ticket Price: $ { this.props.ticket.property1 } </h4> 
            < h4 > Ticket Price: $ { this.props.ticket.property2 } </h4>
            < h4 > Ticket Price: $ { this.props.ticket.property3 } </h4>
            { this.renderReservationInfo() } 
        </div> 
      </div >
        )
      }
    }

export default createContainer(({ ticket }) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('userReservations', ticket._id);
    return {
        UserReservation: UserReservations.find({}).fetch()
    };
}, ComponentName);
```

And my Publication info

```
//Server
Meteor.publish('userReservations', function(ticket_Id) {
      if (!ticket_Id) {
        console.log('No ticketId sent');
      } else {
        console.log('sending UserReservations', ticket_Id);
        return UserReservations.find({ ticketId:ticket_Id });
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this turned out to be a simple enough solution.  I had previously thought I needed to keep my subscribe call empty in the client side for security purposes, and maybe that's an accurate statement, but inserting the the specific ticketId I was able to start returning what I needed to in the correct way.

Also by making stricter query parameters in my publication.find() I was able to limit what was sent back.  I think this is probably an example of a simple problem that I snowballed into a bigger one.